# How to make visual studio c++ project require administrator

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2019

I want my visual studio project to require admin privileges when it is launched, how do you do that?
I've tried going on "properties -> *Project* properties -> linker -> manifest file" and changing the UAC execution level to "requireAdministrator (/level=requireAdministrator'')" but visual studio just gives me error MSB6011 while building the project.
All help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I force my .NET application to run as administrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-do-i-force-my-net-application-to-run-as-administrator)

Comment: @mic: Isn't that exactly what the OP is doing already?

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce your problem, but it didn't work.

I guess it might be something wrong with vs. I suggest that you could try to restore the settings of VS and try again, about restoring the settings of VS: **Tools->Import and Export Settings...->Reset all Settings->Next->"No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings"->Next->General->Finish.**

I suggest you can try to clear the cache of VS.VS cache cleanup steps:

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache directory (2017 correspondence 15.xxx, 2019 correspondence 16.xxx, 2015 correspondence 14.xxx  )
3. Restart Visual Studio.

If the problem persists,I suggest you could try to open the build log function and take a look at the build process.
[image]